# Mac OS cannot mount exFAT disk created on (Ubuntu) linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, macintosh, exfat

I formatted an external hard disk on my ubuntu linux system with exfat.

1. First I installed the exfat utilities: `sudo apt-get install parted exfat-utils`
2. Then I partitioned the disk with a mbr boot record and one primary partition using `parted`
3. Finally I formatted the partition with `mkfs.exfat -n ShareDisk /dev/sdX1`

Then I copied about 300 GB of data onto the disk. Everything worked fine on my linux machine - so far so uneventful.

However, when I plug the disk into my Mac, it says it cannot handle that file system and proposes to initialize or eject it. Now I explicitly chose exfat so the disk would work with any operating system and I have been successfully using exfat formatted disks on my Mac before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just spent the better part of a day solving this problem. Apparently, Mac OS is quite picky about how the partition was created and with which flags.
I was able to solve the problem by

1. Converting the boot record to GPT using `sudo gdisk /dev/sdx` as [suggested here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/exfat-partitions-created-in-linux-not-readable-in-windows-or-mac-os-x-4175575119/#post5523483). Just exit gdisk right away with `w`. It will warn about overwriting your drive. In my case answering with `Y` worked fine without losing data. Please make sure that you have backed up your date before doing this (no backup, no pity).
2. Setting the `msftdata` data on the exfat partition (in my case partition number 1): `sudo parted /dev/sdX` and then `set 1 msftdata on`.

Afterwards my Mac opened the partition without complaints.

Comment: when I do this I hit `invalid VBR checksum 0x0` when mounting the disk after the last step.  I did hit 'you may need to update /etc/fstab` after the final step, which I ignored...

Comment: @jeremy_rutman you may need to trigger a re-discovery of your drive after the gdisk step. The easiest is to unplug and re-plug the drive. Then you can proceed with the parted step.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement [the answer from Thawn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/460155/80216#460156),

For me simply using their solution was not enough.

When I created my partitions using `fdisk`, I first had to create a create a new empty GPT partition table, then the partition, then the filesystem, and then follow the steps they suggested.

The entire process would be (beware as the steps described below will **delete any data** in the existing partitions):

Step 0: Backup any data on the disk that you want to save.

1. Discover the name of the device (in my case `/dev/sdb`)

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
2. Run `fdisk` on the device

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdb                     # replace b by your device letter.
   ```
3. Delete existing partitions (repeat for as many partitions as you have)

   ```
   d
   ```
4. Create the new empty GPT partition table

   ```
   g
   ```
5. Create a new partition

   ```
   n
   ```
6. Choose options. 
   I chose all the default options for the new partition
7. Write the changes to the device

   ```
   w
   ```
8. Write the new exFAT filesystem

   ```
   sudo mkfs.exfat -n my_label /dev/sdb1
   ```
9. Convert the boot record to GPT (Thawn's answer)

   ```
   sudo gdisk /dev/sdb
   ```
10. Just write right away

    ```
    w
    ```
11. Accept that you might lose data (backup first)

    ```
    Y
    ```
12. Set the `msftdata` data on the exFAT partition
    (also taken from Thawn's answer). 
    Since we have only one partition, apply the command to partition 1

    ```
    sudo parted /dev/sdb
    set 1 msftdata on
    q
    ```

Comment: Assuming you already have an exFAT partition(as the question does), your steps 1-9 are unnecessary. On the contrary, especially creating a new partition will certainly delete existing data, which does not (necessarily) happen when you follow my answer.

Comment: You are correct, however when I created the partitions using fdisk (without creating the new empty GPT partition table) and wrote the exFAT fs to it, simply doing steps 10-14 didn't do the trick, so I posted the reply in case someone faces the same issue as I did. I couldn't comment on your reply because don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Maybe add this information to your answer. Also I suggest to add a note that creating the new exFAT filesystem will delete all existing data. It never hurts to be crystal clear when it comes to potential data loss ;-)