# Mystery of the missing disk space

Tags: linux, macintosh, mkfs

I have about ~350Gb that I wanted to copy from server to a new local 1Tb external ssd I bought for the task. So I used rsync but the 1Tb disk ran out of space during the copy, which was odd. So I reformatted (exfat since I wanted access on both mac and linux) and tried again, and noticed that the disk used (`du`) was a lot more than the files themselves warranted (`ls`).  Checking stackexchange it seemed that 'sparse files' or thin provisioning might explain it - but no, sparse files use *less* disk space (as seen by `du`) than the files need (as seen by `ls`) . Finally thinking to check the `du` of individual files, it became apparent that even the smallest file was taking 128K. This was apparently due to the default blocksize when formatting as exfat, and I've got a few million small files in the archive I'm transferring so I can't afford that waste. So on the mac I tried setting 1K blocksize,

```
diskutil info 
diskutil unmountDisk disk4
newfs_exfat -R -v JR_SSD_1Tb -b 1024 /dev/disk4
```

which seemed ok (according to the `diskutil` report)  , but the linux machine didn't automount the ssd and a manual mount ran into an error. So thinking that the mac cli utility wasn't entirely compatible,  I tried formatting on linux  but this doesn't seem to actually do the job: when I create a new testfile of a few bytes its got a 512K minimum size.

```
sudo mkfs.exfat -s 1024 -n JR_SSD  /dev/sda
   mkexfatfs 1.3.0
   Creating... done.
   Flushing... done.a
   File system created successfully.
cat > /media/jeremy/JR_SSD/test.txt
ls -l /media/jeremy/JR_SSD/test.txt
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 jeremy jeremy 4 Aug 25 20:14 /media/jeremy/JR_SSD/test.txt
du -h /media/jeremy/JR_SSD/test.txt
    512K /media/jeremy/JR_SSD/test.txt
```

So - how do I do this ?

Comment: It could be that that's the smallest block exfat can provide for a disk that size.

Comment: Are you planning on actually moving the disk between the systems? Can't you access the disk, attached to one system, from the other system using a network mount or via SSH or other connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-s` option to `mkfs.exfat` is the number of blocks (sectors) per cluster. The cluster is the minimum amount of space that can be manipulated by the filesystem.

You asked for 1024 sectors of 512 bytes per cluster, so the minimum size for a file is 512kibytes. If you want clusters of 1kibytes, use `-s 2`.

Comment: This did the trick. Doing similar from the mac (`newfs_exfat -R -v JR_SDD -b 1024 /dev/disk4`) didn't seem to produce a usable disk. Now I'm onto getting the mac to deal with an HD formatted in this way - this didn't seem to work so far: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460155/mac-os-cannot-mount-exfat-disk-created-on-ubuntu-linux

Comment: on a second try , the hd formatted  on linux using `sudo mkfs.exfat -s 1024 -n JR_SSD  /dev/sda1` was in fact readable from mac